# ctypes only loading dll with winmode = 1

Tags: python, c, windows, dll, ctypes

So I have been trying to build a C .dll that includes the math.h, stdio.h and stdlib.h header files and call it from python using ctypes.

I am using python 3.8 on windows 10, 64 bit.

My problem is that I can only load a dll (compiled with gcc according to https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html) with the `winmode` flag set to 1 like so:

`lib = ctypes.CDLL("name", winmode = 1)`

The dll loads fine and I can call a simple function (that does not depend on header files) just fine in the canonical ctypes-manner. However, as mentioned in the docs, `winmode = 1` sets the Win 32 API `LoadLibraryEx` flags parameter to `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES`. This of course makes it impossible to use any dependencies (e.g. c header files) with the loaded library.

Setting winmode to 0 (default) or None throws a `FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'name' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.`

I have additionally tried:

- using the full path to the .dll when calling ctypes.CDLL
- set `os.add_dll_directory("path_to_dll_folder")`

What might I be missing here?

Comment: Header files are not runtime dependencies.  Any runtime dependency related to them is on the actual library, which for those particular headers would be the standard C runtime library.  Possibly your DLL is looking for the a standard library from Cygwin, though if your Python is built against the MS C runtime then the overall program depending on two different C runtime libraries might well be a problem all of its own.

Comment: You built your *.dll* with *GCC* under *Cygwin*? That requires *cygwin1.dll* to be in *%PATH%*. ?But that's a bad idea, as already stated.